# SnowFlake stored procedure to delete a row from a table based on the date

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-delete

```
create or replace procedure "ETL"."ACQ".SP_FILE_RETENT("Trgt_DB" VARCHAR, "Trgt_Schema" VARCHAR, "Trgt_Table" VARCHAR, "Trgt_Stage" VARCHAR)
returns string
language JavaScript
EXECUTE AS CALLER
as
$$

var remove_data_tbl = `delete from '`+Trgt_Table+`' where last_modified = current_date()`;
var remove_remove_data_tbl_sql = {sqlText: remove_data_tbl };
var remove_data_tbl_create = snowflake.createStatement(remove_remove_data_tbl_sql);
var remove_details_exec = remove_data_tbl_create.execute();

$$;

CALL "ETL"."ACQ".SP_FILE_RETENT('ETL', 'ACQ', 'METADATA', 'FILE_RETENTION');
```

when calling this procedure, it won't delete the rows from my table METADATA
I have back ticks in place before 'delete' and before the + and I have other back ticks after the other plus and before the semi colon

Comment: Are there any errors or just not deleting rows? Is the procedure in the same schema as table? Why do you have parameters for db, schema, but they are not used in the query?

Comment: Tried your procedure and it works for me.

Comment: This only contains part of my procedure, this part above is the only relevant part to my table, theres no errors it just won't delete the row but when I take the code out of the stored procedure or change the +Trgt_Table+ to the actual table name instead it works fine, procedure is in the same schema as the table yes

Comment: Did you check the actual statement that is executed in the history tab? Are you sure table contains values for last_modfied that are equal to current_date?

Comment: Yeah I made sure the last_modified column is in Date format and I inserted values myself for testing using today's date

Comment: I made it into its own procedure for testing by itself and returning this error: Execution error in store procedure SP_TABLE_DATA_RETENT: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 7 unexpected 'fromMETADATAwhere'. syntax error line 1 at position 39 unexpected '<='. At Statement.execute, line 6 position 49 ------ back ticks are in place around the sql statements so unsure how it is reading it all as one string

Comment: Seems like there are some missing spaces!?

Comment: Well, instead of concatenating you could also do something like this: `\`DELETE FROM ${Trgt_Table} where last_modified = current_date()\``

Comment: Yeah the spaces was the issue, thank you, very new to javascript hahah thank you